# Copy and paste to VirtualBox VMs

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have now created a new VM on VirtualBox, configured the machine settings by clicking *"Machine -> Settings -> General -> Advanced"* and then set:

*"Shared Clipboard"* and *"Drag'n Drop"* as *"Bidirectional"*,

then installed and mounted the *Guest Additions*.

But if I try to copy and paste something to VirtualBox VM, it doesn't work at all and if I click on *"Devices->Insert Guest Addditions CD Image"* I get the error: *"Unable to insert the virtual optical disk ...*".

Do you maybe know how I can fix this?

Other information:

Host OS: Windows 8.1

Guest OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1

VBOX 5.2.16

[Storage - GuestAdditions ISO screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84RdM.png)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: How did you install and mount the Guest Additions if you got that error? You know that Guest Additions are for the guest only? That means not mounted nor installed on the host OS (Win8), but in an emulated drive in VBOX for the guest OS(Ubuntu). So if you want to "insert" the image, please look at what @Anurag posted, and check that you have an emulated Optical drive under "Storage" so you can mount the Guest Additions ISO. Also. If it's already mounted in Windows, the file could be locked, so that VBOX can't access it...

Comment: But I have already installed them, even because I have full screen access now. So the question I have is: why am I not able to copy and paste something from my host to guest os?

Comment: The question is still very hard to answer, because there are so very many things that could cause this. But Enabling shared clipboard and drag'n drop before installing the guest additions could lead to problems.

Comment: Try Creating a new VM with Ubuntu 18.04 as guest, then click ok, just accept all defaults, without changing anything. Insert your ISO, and install from it. When setup is finished and the VM has restarted: Insert the Guest Additions iso, and run the install script. Then reboot your VM so the kernel modules are loaded. THEN after the VM is rebooted, and has the Guest Kernel Modules loaded: Enable Drag'n Drop, and Shared clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Guest Additions from the Ubuntu repository, they
might not match the version of VirtualBox, so you might mount the
Guest Additions CD and execute:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox-guest-dkms
sudo /media/$USER/VBox_GAs_5.2.4/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Other things to try :

In the Ubuntu guest, try the following two commands in a terminal:

```
$ killall VBoxClient
$ VBoxClient-all
```

In the Windows host, kill `VBoxTray.exe` using the Task Manager, then restart it
from the installation folder of VirtualBox.

In the Ubuntu guest, try the following command:

```
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work:(

Comment: Unfortunate if it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score -2):

Can you please check whether you have added Optical drive to your VM so you can mount Guest Addtions CD image. You can verify that by clicking on Storage >>

[image]

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Ok, I have just updated my question above with the information requested

Comment: @Ramhound please review answer

Comment: @Giulio see my edited answer can help you or no.

Comment: @AnuragGawande Yes, I have just added a screenshot in the question description above. I should have that

Comment: @AnuragGawande Would you have any other suggestion in here based on the screenshot attached?